# random sampling from exponential / sufficiant statistic

Tags: self-study, exponential-distribution, sufficient-statistics

suppose X ~ exp $ (1/\theta)$  and Y ~ exp $ (2/\theta)$ ,  then why is not X+Y sufficient for $\theta $ ?

this is what i tried , X + Y = X +2Y\2 , let Z= 2Y , then  Z is distributed same as X i.e Z ~ exp $ (1/\theta)$ 
then we must have  X + Z as sufficient for $\theta$ and since X +Z/2 is a one to one function of sufficient statistic it must also be sufficient for $\theta$, isn't it ?
please tell me if i am worng

Comment: Could you try to spell-check your text? e.g., sufficiant should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer your question with a question:  If I generate a realization of $X$ and $Y$ and only tell you that their sum is $11$, would you be able to determine the value of $X + 2Y$?

---

For a statistic to be sufficient for a parameter or parameters, it must not discard information about the parameter(s) that was present in the original sample.  If you are only told $X+Y$, you have lost information about $\theta$ with respect to the fact that one of the realizations that contributed to the sum has a different mean than the other realization.

I'm well aware that you can go through the calculation of the joint density and use the Factorization Theorem to explicitly show that $X+2Y$ is sufficient for $\theta$.  But behind the mechanics of the computation lies the more fundamental principle of understanding what sufficiency means.

Comment: no we would not be able to determine x + 2y ,,, but i dont understand whay u r askin dat

Comment: @ANUJNAIN: In other words, $X+2Y$ is not in one-to-one relation with $X+Y$....